# $m(A \cap B)=0.9 \ m(A \cap C)=0.9 \ m(C \cap B)=0.9 \ m(A \cup B \cup C)=1$ Prove that $m(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 0.85$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let A,B and C be measurable sets on the real line such that $$m(A \cap B)=0.9 \ \ \ m(A \cap C)=0.9 \ \ \ m(C \cap B)=0.9 \ \ \ \ m(A \cup B \cup C)=1$$
Prove that $$m(A \cap B \cap C) \geq 0.85$$

Any Hint\idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The principle of inclusion and exclusion would be perfect here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: @Ragnar The principle of inclusion and exclusion says $$m(A \cup B \cup C)=m(A) + m(B) + m(C) - m(A \cap B) - m(B \cap C) - m(A \cap C) + m(A \cap B \cap C)$$ I don't see how to deal with $m(A) \ , m(B)\ , \ m(C)$ having no info about them, Should I approximate their measure being bigger than the corresponding intersections ? but that does not seem to be helpful, can you tell me how to use this principle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete proof:

Since
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

$$P(A)+P(B) = P(A \cup B) + P(A \cap B) \le 1.9$$
$$P(A)+P(C) = \le 1.9$$
$$P(B)+P(C) = 
 \le 1.9$$
Adding
$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C) \le \frac{1.9+1.9+1.9}{2} = 2.85$$

From inclusion exclusion principle
$$
P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A\cup B\cup C) +P(A\cap B)+ P( B\cap C)+P(A\cap C) -(P(A)+P(B)+P(C))
\ge 1 + 0.9+0.9+0.9 - 2.85 = 0.85$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. A Venn diagram would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You must be referring to Venn diagram. Is that another name for it?

Comment: Thnx - Correction made.

Answer (score 1):

This is best done with the number line as a venn diagram. Let $A$ be the interval *starting* at 0 and $B$ be an interval *ending* at 1. You are given that there is a 90% overlap. 
Now $C$ makes 90% overlap with both $A$ and $B$. The most $C$ can leave out is 5% on either side or C should overlap $A \cap B$ by 85%

Comment: That's a good intuitive idea, but you can not assume $A$ and $B$ be such nice sets, they might for example be some subset of the complement of the Cantor set occupying 90% of it. Do you know how to rigorously show it i general ?

Comment: Updated my answer with actual calculations. Thanks for making me get past my inertia!